# ExpressJS cannot get /route in Openshift, but locally it is working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular-ui-router, openshift

My project have this following structure.

```
server.js
/node_modules
/build
    vendor.js
    main.js
    index.html
```

I'm using express, and AngularJS's `ui-router`.

In `server.js` I have this code:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/build/index.html');
});
```

And locally it is working if I pass `localhost:8080/hellothere`, I get the correct page but when I've deployed, it doesn't.

Within the application if use the links to navigate the routes run, the URL is modified to `/hellothere`, but if I update the page or try to go straight to the absolute URL I get:

```
Cannot GET /hellothere
```

I'm already have tryied put:

```
app.get('/page1', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/build/index.html');
});

app.get('/page2', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/build/index.html');
});
...
```

And the behavior is the same of `'/*'`. Fine local, broke on cloud.

Any idea what's happening here?

[homolog Website link](http://front-210diner.rhcloud.com/sobre)

Comment: There is not enough information here to be able to help you.

Comment: http://front-210diner.rhcloud.com/ its working; http://front-210diner.rhcloud.com/sobre it doesn't.

but, in localhost it is working.

Comment: both of those are giving internal server errors....

Comment: strange.. here the first is working

Comment: You can check OpenShift logs for more clues on what's happening, by running `rhc tail <your_app_name>`

Answer (score 0):

> And locally it is working if I pass `localhost:8080/hellothere`, I get
>   the correct page but when I've deployed, it doesn't.

The possible reason might be after deploying your base url might be `domainname.com/appname` and your local code is for `localhost:portNumber` not for `localhost:portNumber/appname`

So modify your path to

```
app.get('/appname/hellothere', function(req, res) {
    res.send("hellothere is working");
});
```

instead of

```
app.get('/hellothere', function(req, res) {
        res.send("hellothere is working");
    });
```

To run it locally, now you will need `localhost:portNumber/appname/hellothere`